# Unable to connect to MongoDB cluster running on Openshift

Tags: database, mongodb, kubernetes, openshift

I have created a mongodb cluster on openshift.
Everything is running. The logs show that pod is waiting for connections. But I am unable to connect to it from studio 3T on my local machine.

Here is my route file that I created.

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: mongodb
  port:
    targetPort: 27017
```

And my Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    template.openshift.io/expose-uri: 'mongodb://{.spec.clusterIP}:{.spec.ports[?(.name=="mongo")].port}'
  creationTimestamp: '2024-02-06T17:33:53Z'
  labels:
    template: mongodb-persistent-template
    template.openshift.io/template-instance-owner: e5e0ff4d-c515-11ee-9e90-fa163eb4bd92
  name: mongodb
  namespace: pwp
  resourceVersion: '2280249831'
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/pwp/services/mongodb
  uid: e5ea8073-c515-11ee-9e90-fa163eb4bd92
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.30.50.41
  ports:
    - name: mongo
      port: 27017
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    name: mongodb
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Can someone please guide me what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.